# Table from logs in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have an array of values coming directly from database from table with columns ("Name", "Email","ProductId", Quantity). The data looks like this:

```
{'data':[
    ('Tom', 'tom1234@gmail.com','P1231', 50),
    ('Rob', 'robasq@gmail.com','P6431', 100),
    ('Nick', 'nicasa@gmail.com','P3231', 40),
    ('Li', 'lichan@gmail.com','P1231', 60)]}
```

I want to use this array from the logs and display as a table or as a chart in dashboard in Splunk. Does someone know if this is possible in Splunk Enterprise. For eg

```
Name           Email           ProductId     Quantity
Tom    tom1234@gmail.com        P1231         50
Rob    robasq@gmail.com         P6431        100
Nick   nicasa@gmail.com         P3231         40
Li     lichan@gmail.com         P1231         60
```

Answer (score 0):

`| spath | table *`

[spath](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Spath) is used to extract information from structured data (JSON, XML, etc...)

You may also wish to specify the exact fields you are after in the table, rather than use `*`

Are you using `dbconnect` to bring this data in, or ingesting it in some other manner?